# I think I am stuck on a workspace. No icons on desktop w/Ubuntu as guest in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, workspaces

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as a guest on a Win10 box with virtualbox 5.2. I can see the normal desktop in the preview pane of VB but my desktop does not show at all.. just the background. How do I get to the icon screen? Is on a different workspace?[screen grab showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KsK7.png)

Update: If I try to quit the guest, it displays the icon screen..[update on ctrl+q guest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MypCu.png)

Comment: Does the "Windows" key make the launcher visible?  If you move the mouse to the left edge (or upper left corner) does the launcher become visible?

Comment: Try launching Nautilus if it is not already runing.

Comment: no to Windows key. But powering down and unchecking 3d acceleration gets me to the icons on the desktop. I guess 3d Acceleration in VB is bad?